# File permission forbidden, but can be accessed when the name changed

Tags: linux, apache, unix, permissions

I've a web app where user can upload their ID card picture. When they upload the picture, I name the picture with `[username]_[timestamp].[extension]`

This is work fine for almost all of the picture uploaded. But there is a few picture, that when I try to access it in the browser, it says I don't have permission to access the file. One of the example of the file name is `hsigit_2015-11-28 09:12:48.jpg`.

The permission and the naming pattern is the same with any other file that can be accessed without problem. Only this file and several other (about 5 files) that can't be accessed from browser.

But when I change the name to something like `eror.png`,  or `eror12345.png`, suddenly it can be accessed. But when I change the name to something like `hsigit_2015-11-28.jpg` or `hsigit.jpg`, it still can not be accessed.

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: It may be a rule that forbids some pattern in file names? Maybe the word `git`?

Comment: Hey, I think you're right, all the file that got the problem has substring `git` in it. Thank you. Would you like to move your comment to the answer, so I can mark it as the right answer? 
Also, how can I change the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a rule that forbids some pattern in file names? Maybe the word `git`?

Have a look at your `http.conf` and subsequents there is probably something like :

```
<Directorymatch "^/.*/\.git/">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directorymatch>
```

or `Filesmatch`. Adapt the pattern to meet your needs.

Comment: I found it on .htaccess file. I change it from `<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">` to `<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|\.git)">`. Is it right?

Comment: Should be much better, modify the same way for others, you will have the same problem in some near future :-)